# Translate ISO 639-1 to python locale

Tags: python, locale, python-telegram-bot

My main aim is to correctly setting `locale` from `update.effective_user.language_code` in a python telegram bot

```py
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, update.effective_user.language_code)
```

`update.effective_user.language_code` returns ISO 639-1 codes, which for example, sets `es` for Spanish. However, `locale` is expecting something like `es_ES` in Debian Buster, for example.

Surprisingly, in Windows, it is working, somehow, as it internally converts it to `es_ES`.

I tried installing in Debian Buster `locales-all` but the `es` code doesn't appear when I issue an `locale -a`

The error I get is:

```
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

I am using Python 3.11

Comment: "correctly": you cannot do it (you lack information: e.g. with `en`, which English variant do you want to show). AFAIK nobody really choose a *best* fallback in such cases (and such fallbacks (+ other options) are described for web [content has more nuances then a terminal), and so later then Unix locales)). Just at initialization, read the output of `locale -a` and create an option of 2 letters codes (and maybe also an override, but good luck to find a good default for `pt`

Comment: iso-639-3 is not suitable. You'd need BCP-47 language tag, but certain aspects of POSIX locales aren't supproted by BCP-47 and the BCP-47 U extension supports many aspects  that don't map cleanly to POSIX locales. Ignoring the fact that different libc implementations have different sets of locales, and localedata can differ between libc implementations. Also, should es match es_ES or should it match es_AR, es_BO, es_CL, es_CO, es_CR, es_CU, es_DO, es_EC, es_ES@euro, es_GT, es_HN, es_MX, es_NI, es_PA, es_PE, es_PR, es_PY, es_SV, es_US, es_UY, or es_VE, etc.